# Forcing Dynamic Encoding only in zlib c++ library

Tags: c++, zlib

I was wondering if it would be possible to force the zlib library (c++) to encode the compressed file in dynamic huffman only (no literal or fixed). I am looking at the Advance Functions in the zlib manual and under `deflateInit2,` it has the following parameters to select upon:

- 196 #define Z_FILTERED            1
- 197 #define Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY        2
- 198 #define Z_RLE                 3
- 199 #define Z_FIXED               4
- 200 #define Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY    0

I am using default strategy, but up to a certain file size, it would start producing static huffman encodes. Will changing it to huffman_only ensure the desired behaviour? Is it even possible to have a guarantee of only dynamic encoding? I am using this to test my self-built decompressor. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zlib does not have an option to force only dynamic blocks. Huffman-only would not guarantee that, as stored blocks would be smaller for random data.